# Authorize In Asp.Net Core Without Identity

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, authorization, roles, asp.net-authorization

In Asp.net Core 3
I have two admin and user values ​​in my database (for roles) that I want to use to authorize. I don't want to use Identity.
Please help me

Comment: how do you want to validate..form based authentication?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you don't want to use default `Identity`, Microsoft has provided many ways to custom this. You can read in [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/cookie?view=aspnetcore-3.1) for using Cookie Authentication without Identity or [Custom Policy-based](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/policies?view=aspnetcore-3.1).

Comment: Johnathan, the link you shared is `Use cookie authentication without ASP.NET Core Identity`. How can I check the role using the IsInRole method?